# MongoDB multiple condition in WHERE clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB i have to give OR condition in WHERE clause

I am a beginner. I dont know how to acheive this?

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id = 6 OR id =8
```

What is the similar query in MongoDB??

Comment: Have you tried reading...the documentation?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the $or operator as described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

```
db.tablename.remove({ $or: [ { _id: 6 }, { _id: 8 } ] })
```

You may also find the appropriate section in the manual for [SQL comparison](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) useful.